# After getting socket data call separate thread for further processing?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Currently I have this socket programme which will recieve data from the devices and then do a lengthy process like checking for geo fence and other relevant logic and finally saves data into the db. Below is how my codes looks

This the code to start the socket
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
      new commS();
   }
   commS() { 

   try {
      // setup the connection pool
            HikariConfig  config = new HikariConfig ();
            config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/****"); 
            config.setUsername("*****"); 
            config.setPassword("*****");      
            config.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
            //config.setPartitionCount(1);
            connectionPool = new HikariDataSource(config); // setup the connection pool         
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
      }
      try 
      {
               final ServerSocket serverSocketConn = new ServerSocket(8000);                
               while (true) 
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                                Socket socketConn1 = serverSocketConn.accept();
                                new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(socketConn1)).start();                     
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("MyError:Socket Accepting has been caught in main loop."+e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                        }
                    }
      } 
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
         System.out.println("MyError:Socket Conn has been caught in main loop."+e.toString());
         e.printStackTrace(System.out);
         //System.exit(0); 
      }
```

Here is the rest of the socket connection codes which does the connection handler.

```
class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
      private Socket receivedSocketConn1;
    ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
      this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
    }

public void run() { // etc
     w = null;
     BufferedReader r = null;  
     String message="";
     try {
          /// here I read for the data and call the rest of the function etc.
          I would like to split into separate thread? 
     }
     catch (SocketTimeoutException ex)  
          { 
               System.out.println("MyError:SocketTimeoutException has been caught in in the main first try");
               ex.printStackTrace();
          }  
          catch (IOException ex)  
          { 
               System.out.println("MyError:IOException has been caught in in the main first try");
               ex.printStackTrace();
          }  


}
```

I have marked /// here I read for the data and call the rest of the function etc. In that run function I receive data, verify and call all various other function etc and finally save the data into the db. I feel this is a lengthy process. I want to  break  it two section one just to read the data and then pass this string of data to separate thread so  is below what I am trying to achieve is correct.

So in the run function I plan to do this Thread t = new Thread(new MyRProcessing (parameter));
   t.start(); I am not too sure is this correct? Should I write the MyRProcessing as separate .java or put all into one java?

```
public class MyRProcessing implements Runnable {
      private X parameter;
      public MyRProcessing (X parameter) {
         this.parameter = parameter;
      }

      public void run() {
      }
   }
```

Comment: You might want to read a few multithreading tutorials before getting into it. It's a complex subject and since you're asking so many questions, you'll probably be in over your head if you try to "wing it". Otherwise this seems like it could benefit at least a little from a producer-consumer pattern, if you have a long running process.

Comment: Yes I have read some and google and this where I found about calling this Thread t = new Thread(new MyRProcessing (parameter));

Comment: I need some kind of confirmation whether what I am trying to do is correct or not? Actually my problem is simple I want to break into two separate thread reading as one and the rest of the processing I want to pass to separate thread so that the main thread is not overloaded with all the other processing?

Comment: You need to read more.

Comment: Is there any good link you will suggest? I have been googling on this maybe on a wrong direction?

Comment: Look into producer-consumer pattern. I can guarantee you'll run into plenty of problems if you just google for snippets and try to insert them into your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126659/discussion-between-user5313398-and-kayaman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example for producer-consumer [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_procon.htm)

This deals with the general question of [multithreading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html), I highly recommend reading up on those before proceeding.

The simplest way to do what you are proposing is to simply extend the Thread class and pass your data in via the constructor, then processing it in the `run()` method. This isn't the best way to go about doing it in most cases, but it is simple.

Ex.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private String data;
    public MyThread(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void run() { /* process data */ }
}
```

and then just start up the thread, once it's done, it'll return and the thread will terminate.

Comment: thank you for the link yes I was trying to achieve the simplest and fastest way to convert my codes cause there quite lengthy?

Comment: in your opinion should I leave my current codes or change to this producer-consumer codes?  Will there be heavy impact with my current codes in terms of memory usage and scalability its working fine so far just worried about future?

Comment: producer-consumer is probably better in the long run. You probably won't notice any performance issues either way. If you are only expecting a few threads to be running at once, doing it the simple way is probably just fine. One problem is that this can choke your computer if you get too many running at once. It all depends on what you are doing

Comment: @so far running on this single run function and then calling multiple functions in it is functioning well I dont really see a big problem only that the I dont know whether it impact on the device by me holding and doing a length process?

Comment: Depends on how many simultaneous connections you are expecting and how intensive the operations you want to do are. If you are only expecting a few connections, you likely won't notice any issues at all, it'll just take up a little more memory. Modern hardware has been very well optimized to handle a great many simultaneous threads so it only really becomes an issue in large applications

Comment: @let say I am going to have at maximum say 2000 simultaneous connection if even it happens so which way to go with my current to way to split?  My worry is that by split infact its going to take up more memory cause I need to create extra threads right?

Comment: If you have 2000 simultaneous connections, it means you'll have around 4000 threads running (2000 for reading the data, 2000 for processing). With this method, that would likely cripple your CPU and consume a huge amount of memory (on the order of several GB). In that case you absolutely would want to use a producer-consumer system, probably with a Thread Pool

Comment: @I have been reading about producer and consumer is like put thing into queue I am worried about sequence of data coming and being processed and also the time taken to process will there be any impact on this later if I use producer and consumer?

Comment: Having it in a queue simply means it'll be processed in a first come first serve basis. As for performance, if you want it to be very high performance, look into [thread pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)

Comment: just to clarify now is that in my case the reading thread is considered the producer right? Then the consumer thread will the processing thread right?

Comment: that is correct. If it helps, think of it like a restaurant, it produces the food, the customers (threads) consume the food. But the restaurant has only so much space for customers so you can't have too many of them.

Comment: so how to set in the consumer to have the database pooling? So are you suggesting from the multiple producer it will go into a single consumer or multiple consumer?

Comment: You'll have multiple producers (the reading threads) but a shared consumer (whether that's 1 or more than 1 depends on how much work you want to do). For the database, you'll have to research whatever database you are using how it handles concurrency.

Comment: I am clear now so its multiple producer and either single or more? So in my scenario say its going to be 2000 producer what do you suggest surely not single consumer right? Currently I am using hikari connection pooling for my single method? How to cater that for my consumer ?

Comment: This is getting a little off topic, I recommend creating another question specifically about producer-consumer, connection and thread pooling

Comment: Sure I will do that later thank you for your guidance.